# Script for trimming with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, scripts, ffmpeg

I'm recording radio broadcasts via DVB-C and gnutv. To trim the recordings I use ffmpeg.

The synthax takes rahter long to enter in Terminal. So I'm working on a script to automatize this. Hiere it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Getting the input file:
read -e -p "Enter the absolute path for the .mpg-file: " PATH
# Start time of trimming:
read -p "Where should the trimming start? (Please enter in this format hh:mm:ss): " START
# End time of trimming:
read -p "When should the trimming end? (Please enter in this format hh:mm:ss): " END
# Informations about the song:
read -p "What song is it? " TITLE
read -p "Who sang it? " ARTIST
read -p "Which album?" ALBUM
# Determine the duration of trimming (given in seconds).
START2=$(echo $START | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
END2=$(echo $END | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
DURATION=$(expr $END2 - $START2)
ffmpeg -ss $ANFANG -i $PATH -t $DURATION -acodec copy -vcodec copy -metadata title=$TITLE -metadata author=$ARTIST $TITLE' · '$ARTIST'.mpg'
```

When I run this script for "St. Elmos Fire" by "John Parr", I get:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'Elmo's'
```

I think it is beacause of the whitespaces in $TITLE and $ARTIST. I already tried \ and '' as well as the -e option for read. But it produces a similar error message. What am I doing wrong?

Best regards an thanks in advance,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, and most importantly, do not use uppercase variable names. You risk overriding environment variables and special shell variables, and in this case you did just that by overwriting the `PATH` variable.

Second. Quotes are very very important in shell scripting; quoting variable expansions avoids the result from being subjected to pathname expansion and word splitting.

For example, if `var="St. Elmo's Fire.mpg"`, then `$var` will become the three words `St.`, `Elmo's` and `Fire.mpg`, while `"$var"` will become the one word `St. Elmo's Fire.mpg`. So always quote variable expansions. `"$var"`, not `$var`.

Something like this should be more correct:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -ep "Enter path for the .mpg-file: " file
IFS=: read -rp "Where should the trimming start? (HH:MM:SS): " shour smin ssec
IFS=: read -rp "When should the trimming end? (HH:MM:SS): " ehour emin esec
read -rp "What song is it? " title
read -rp "Who sang it? " artist
read -rp "Which album?" album

start=$(( shour*3600 + smin*60 + ssec ))
end=$(( ehour*3600 + emin*60 + esec ))
duration=$(( end - start ))

ffmpeg -i "$file" -t "$duration" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -metadata "title=$title" \
       -metadata "author=$artist" "$title · $artist.mpg"
```

Your ffmpeg command had `-ss "$ANFANG"`, but `ANFANG` was never set in your script, so I omited it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly now. The original script is german. I missed to replace "ANFANG"=beginning. I guess, this is also why PATH wasn't a problem, because in my german script it was PFAD.